# Progress Bar findviewbyid returns null

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Help me please it's getting frustrating!

i'm doing a chat application where i'm adding views to a linear layout programmatically each time a user press the send button the code is below:

```
public  void appendToMessageHistory(String id,String uname, String messa,String messageType, final String filepath, String DownloadStatus,boolean internet,int type) {


    //TextView tv=new TextView(Messaging.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_entity, null);


    TextView mess;
    TextView time;
    final ImageView iv;
    final ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView statusiv;
    if (friend.userName.equals(uname)) {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_entity, null);
        v.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        mess = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_message);
        time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_time);
        iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_imageview);
        statusiv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_progressbar);
    } else {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_entity_right, null);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        v.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        mess = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_message);
        time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_time);
        iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_imageview);
        statusiv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewleft);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_Right_progressbar);
    }

    try {
        progressBar.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (messageType != null) {
        if (messageType.equals(MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_PIC)) {
            iv.setImageBitmap(ImageHandlet.GetBitmapFromPath(filepath));
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filepath), "image/png");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("FIlePAth", filepath);
                }
            });

        } else if (messageType.equals(MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO)) {
            if (DownloadStatus.equals(LocalStorageHandler.DOWNLOADED)) {
                if(!(friend.userName.equals(uname))) {
                    if (type != 3) {
                        Bitmap bitTh = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filepath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bitTh);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(filepath));
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filepath), "video/mp4");
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Log.w("Zipping","Progress Bar");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    Bitmap bitTh = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filepath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitTh);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(filepath));
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filepath), "video/mp4");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else if (DownloadStatus.equals(LocalStorageHandler.NotDOWNLOADED)) {
                iv.setTag(id);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Cursor c = localstoragehandler.getIDnfo(iv.getTag().toString());
                        String filepath = "";
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplication(),iv.getTag().toString()+" iD " +iv.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        while (c.moveToNext()) {
                            String msg0 = c.getString(0);
                            String msg2 = c.getString(2);
                            String msg3 = c.getString(3);
                            String msg4 = c.getString(4);
                            String msg5 = c.getString(5);
                            String msg6 = c.getString(6);

                            filepath = msg5;

                            Log.d("-----------Vedio-----", "------------------");
                            Log.d("DATABASE---------", msg0);
                            Log.d("DATABASE-------", msg2);
                            Log.d("DATABASE---------", msg3);
                            Log.d("DATABASE-----", msg4 + "");
                            Log.d("DATABASE-------", msg5 + "");
                            Log.d("DATABASE----------", msg6 + "");
                            Log.d("--------END-------", "-------END-----------");


                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filepath.toString() + iv.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        DownloadFileFromURL downloadFileFromURL = new DownloadFileFromURL(filepath, iv.getTag().toString());
                        downloadFileFromURL.execute("");
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    if(!(messageType.equals(MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO))) {
        if (!internet) {
            statusiv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noconnectionl);
        }
    }
    mess.setText(messa);
    //time.setText(sendt);
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    final View lastview = v;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mEssageBox.addView(lastview);

        }
    });
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            messageText.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the XML of the dialogbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewleft"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/chaticion" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tests"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#83e3ed"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewleft"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewleft">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_entity_right_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="Large ffText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_entity_right_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_entity_right_message"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_entity_right_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_entity_right_time"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/message_entity_Right_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_entity_right_time"


        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code to send the video message:

```
final String message = messageText.getText().toString();
    final Long rowid = localstoragehandler.insert(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message, MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO, ZippedVideoPath, LocalStorageHandler.DOWNLOADED); //insert data into db and get to chat_id
    appendToMessageHistory(rowid + "", imService.getUsername(), message, MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO, ZippedVideoPath, LocalStorageHandler.DOWNLOADED, internet,3);// append the video with type 3 to just display the progress 
    messageText.setText("Video");
    String newstr = null;
    // intialize the asynctask to upload the video
    class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog uploading;
        View V;
        UploadVideo(View v){
            V = v;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //          uploading = ProgressDialog.show(Messaging.this, "Uploading File", "Please wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return imService.sendVideoMessage(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message, MessageInfo.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO, "", ZippedVideoPath);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
         //   RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) V.findViewById(rowid.intValue());
        //    Log.w("Zipping",v.toString());
     //       ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) V.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_Right_progressbar);
      //      Log.w("Zipping",progressBar1.toString());
            //          ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_imageview);
       //     progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //  Log.d("POST Execute", s + "");

            //textViewResponse.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Uploaded at <a href='" + s + "'>" + s + "</a></b>"));
            //textViewResponse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    // here i am preparing the path so when the compress is done to save into.
        }
    }
    if (null != absolute && absolute.length() > 0) {
        int endIndex = absolute.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            newstr = absolute.substring(endIndex, absolute.length()); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
        }
    }
    Log.w("Zipping", newstr);
    final File videosdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/videos/");
    if (!videosdir.exists()) {
        videosdir.mkdirs();
    }
    ZippedVideoPath = videosdir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + newstr;
    Log.w("Zipping", ZippedVideoPath);
    // here i got the ffmpeg library from the net to compress the video and i'm preparing the commands
    String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", absolute, "-strict", "experimental", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:a", "150k", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", ZippedVideoPath};
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getBaseContext());
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(complexCommand, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.w("Zipping", "started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.w("Zipping", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message1) {
                Log.w("Zipping","Success");
                RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) mEssageBox.findViewById(rowid.intValue());
                Log.w("VideoView",v.toString());
                ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_Right_progressbar);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_imageview);
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitTh = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(ZippedVideoPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitTh);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ZippedVideoPath));
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(ZippedVideoPath), "video/mp4");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo(v);
                uv.execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.w("Zipping", e.toString());
    }
}
```

okay now to the problem when i call the findviewbyid for the progress bar in sendvideomessage ffmpeg onsuccess callback it returns null even though the findviewbyid for the the imageview which is in the same layout it returns the view! so please tell me what is the problem

```
public void onSuccess(String message1) {
                Log.w("Zipping","Success");
                RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) mEssageBox.findViewById(rowid.intValue()); ;
                ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_Right_progressbar); // this keeps returning null!
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_entity_right_imageview); // returns the view
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bitmap bitTh = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(ZippedVideoPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitTh);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ZippedVideoPath));
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(ZippedVideoPath), "video/mp4");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo(v);
                uv.execute();
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it always return null or does it work when you press send  the first time?

Comment: do you mean in the appendToMessageHistory ? no it doesn't return null the progress visibility is set to visible and i can see it spinning in front of me but in the onsuccuess it always returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find the view as a child to "v" which seems to be a sibling to the progress bar, not a parent.

Edit: But tbh it's a bit hard to follow the code since you seem to reuse the rowid as the view id. Is this even what you intended?
When adding views programmatically they don't get any id so you'd have a hard time finding views with the rowid as an id. I guess you could use tags and iterate through views to find a tag, but this is a horribly inefficient solution.

(Try finding the view using the view root, or at least one that is actually a parent to the view you're looking for.
Also, don't do this multiple times, save your views as members.)

And furthermore, don't add views dynamically in a linearlayout that grows indefinitely. You will eventually run out of memory. Use a recyclerview and a n adapter to have views created, reused and destroyed as needed while you scroll.

Comment: i heard about the issue with memory, but i went too further into the codding tho change everything now, i'm setting the view the row_id which is the chat id in the DB to make it easier to findviewbyid so i don't have to iterate through all the views as you suggested.

Comment: Well, every programmer runs into a problem that forces you to rethink and redesign. Refactoring is what I do to improve my code probably 50% of the time. Don't continue in the wrong direction just because you already spent some time on it. And do not try to use row ids as view ids as view ids are the ones you statically assign in xml and whose values are auto-generated by aapt during build.

Comment: i read somewhere that automatically generated views doesn't have an id..., i know what you mean by having to refactor everything but i got no time at all... really i'm working alone

Comment: Then you're in trouble..sooner or later you will regret not doing things properly from the start. Unless this is just a school assignment or.something short-lived.

Comment: exactly its a temp project for now.

Comment: Then try findViewWithTag

and set your rowid as the tag.

Comment: Ohh Okay will try out and reply to you tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Hello Jhh i tried your suggestion but the whole relative layout cannot be found now .. i did settag instead of setid and used findviewwithtag to get the view but it returned null

Comment: Impossible to say what's wrong now without knowing what you did. You have to debug and learn from mistakes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Based on JHH Answer, i tried what he suggested to set a tag for the layout and call it from there it didn't work so i tried to set the tag for the progress bar and and findviewbytag for the progress bar and it worked! strange behavior, anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a final variable:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar;
```

It ll be initialized only once. You cannot reassign a new value to it in the same context.

Try removing `final` or use separate `ProgressBar` variables for two different layouts and see if it works.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: As JHH suggested, use a RecyclerView. Makes things easy and efficient!

Comment: If this was the problem the code would not compile while trying to assign the variable the second time.clearly this is not the issue.

Comment: that's exactly what i was thinking JHH